# How to change action parameters and get it to work without changing routing in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

In my route I have something like this:

```
controller/action/{id}
```

To my knowledge this means it will call any action with the parameter id like the following:

```
public ActionResult Detail(string id) 
{
}
```

What do I have to do to make the following work without registering the particular route in global.asax file:

```
public ActionResult Detail(string customerId) 
{
}
```

Comment: do you just want to rename the parameter? Or do you want two different actions? Or are these two actions in different controllers? You would not be able to have these two actions in the same controller because the signatures are the same.

Comment: Just rename the parameters. I will have a single action named "Detail".

Answer (score -2, accepted):

have a route like - controller/action/{customerId} or just rename the parameter `customerId` to `id` and then use it the particular way you want.

Comment: yeah I know I can do that but is there anyway to do this at the action level instead of the global.asax file level.

Comment: well at the action level only..rename it to id from customer id and it will work..

Comment: Yes! but I like to name it customerId instead of id. I thought I can define routes at action level using attributes.

Comment: nope..not at action level...mvc defines its routing(RegisterRoutes) in global.asax and needs to know what to look for...read more about it here -http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

Answer (score 14):

If you really don't want to rename the method parameter, you can use BindAttribute to tell MVC what its logical name should be:

```
public ActionResult Detail([Bind(Prefix = "id")] string customerId)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass customerId as query string, which is normally what I do:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Detail", "Detail", new { @customerId = Model.CustomerID}, null)%>
```

MVC does not enforce the routing, but rather try to resolve routing based on your url AND query string.