# How to apply BindAttribute.Prefix to an action method parameter of type Int32?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When I apply `BindAttribute.Prefix` to an action parameter `value`, I would expect `DefaultModelBinder` to either use the *custom prefix* or fall back to an `empty prefix` ( in either case `value` parameter would be assigned number `100` ). But instead it does neither and as such the following code throws an exception:

*The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'value' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32)'*

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "originalPrefix")]int value)
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
 using (Html.BeginForm())
 {      
       <input id="originalPrefix.value" name="originalPrefix.value" type="text" value="100" />
       <input id="value" name="value" type="text" value="100" />

       <input type="submit" value="submit" />
 }
```

a) Why isn't `DefaultModelBinder` able to bind *form data* to `value` parameter?

b) If possible, how do we apply `BindAttribute.Prefix` to an action method parameter of type Int32?

thank you

Comment: Related: [How to change action parameters and get it to work without changing routing in asp.net mvc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4749499/11683)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the `name` attribute should be `"originalPrefix"` not `"originalPrefix.value"`. You're trying to bind the parameter and not the value property of the parameter.

Comment: It works now, but since in this situation the prefix isn't really used as a prefix, but as a name of the form data element, are there any situations where applying BindAttribute.Prefix to a simple type parameters ( such as int ) would prove useful ?

Comment: As far as I know, applying to simple parameters _is_ one of it's intended uses. The syntax just looks weird.